# Odds of Ratio of 1 in logistic regression

Tags: sas

I'm working with a dataset from Gapminder (www.gapminder.org), and I've been running some logistic regressions. As I understand it, if you get an Odds Ratio of exactly 1, then then interpretation is that there cannot be a significant difference. However, in the model I also get a p-value of 0.0010 which suggests significance.

Is this possible, or (more likely) have I misspecified something? [image]

Comment: Judging from the first table, yes it is possible, because the standard error is very low. However, in practice the odds ratio is very close to 1. See the confidence interval in the second table.

Comment: In a sense you may have misspecified as @Scortchi's comment indicates. If you divide income by some suitable value like 1000 you will get a more useful range for the OR and its CI

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you mistake statistical significance with practical (in my field, clinical) significance.

Your results show that there was a statistically significant effect. The odds ratio was $e^{0.000089}=1.000089004$, which was rounded by SAS to 1.000. In fact, the 95% confidence interval does not include 1, having the following limits: 1.00003608 and 1.00014193. Technically, this is not correct to say that $OR==1$. Practically, however, this predictor has a vanishingly small effect on the outcome.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I'd take issue with your last sentence. A unit increase in the predictor may indeed have a very (not "vanishingly", which implies approaching some limit) small effect on the outcome, but how big is a unit? There's no context given; but it's tempting to suppose that `incomeperperson` is being measured in pounds or dollars, say, per year, & to speculate that the odds ratio of 2.43 corresponding to an increase of £10k or $10k in annual income isn't negligible.